# Extract images and text from a sequence of urls

Tags: python, web-scraping

I'm trying to make an script to extract images and text from a sequence of urls. The urls are from the same website but with differents parameters. Reading StackOverflow and another sites I have "created" a script that works, but I have a problem when I try to make a sequence.

I tryed to use a while to make a loop and determine that if the option input is "1" the script have to make a range (00001, 00002...) and then apply it to an url (`http://example.com/page/00001`). Everything works (even the image and text extraction) but it only extract from one url. I have tried to make a list or something else but I haven't gotten it.

Here is the code that works but only extract from one:

```py
def getUrl(opt, baseUrl):
    out_folder = "/monedasWiki/monedas"
    print "Instrucciones del script \n No te preocupes, no es complicado pero atiende a los pasos"
    print "Introduce 1 para obtener los archivos del 00001 al 00010"
    print "Introduce 2 para obtener los archivos del 00010 al 00099"
    print "Introduce 3 para obtener los archivos del 00100 al 00999"
    print "Introduce 4 para obtener los archivos del 01000 al 09999"
    print "Introduce 5 para obtener los archivos del 10000 al 19999"
    optSel = int(input(opt))
    # i es el rango
    # urlI es la transformacion de i en cadena
    # baseUrl es el enlace al sitio web de Pliego
    # url es la url completa con los parametros necesarios
    while True:
        if optSel == 1:
            try:
                for i in range(0,10):
                    r = str(0).zfill(4)
                    urlI = str(i)
                    print r + urlI # it's only to verify that works fine.
                    url = baseUrl + r + urlI
            except ValueError:
                print "Introduce el rango correcto"
                continue
        elif optSel == 2:
            try:
                for i in range(10,100):
                    r = str(0).zfill(3)
                    urlI = str(i)
                    print r + urlI # it's only to verify that works fine.
                    url = baseUrl + r + urlI
            except ValueError:
                print "Introduce el rango correcto"
                continue
        elif optSel < 0:
            print "Valor inferior a 0"
            continue
        else:
            print "Algo ha salido mal"
            break

        main(url, out_folder)
```

I just put two `elif` to make the code shortest. If you could point me where or what it's the mistake and what could I do to make what I want, I'll be thankful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on what main() does, something like this:

```
def getUrl(opt, baseUrl):
    out_folder = "/monedasWiki/monedas"
    print "Instrucciones del script \n No te preocupes, no es complicado pero atiende a los pasos"
    print "Introduce 1 para obtener los archivos del 00001 al 00010"
    print "Introduce 2 para obtener los archivos del 00010 al 00099"
    print "Introduce 3 para obtener los archivos del 00100 al 00999"
    print "Introduce 4 para obtener los archivos del 01000 al 09999"
    print "Introduce 5 para obtener los archivos del 10000 al 19999"
    optSel = int(input(opt))
    # i es el rango
    # urlI es la transformacion de i en cadena
    # baseUrl es el enlace al sitio web de Pliego
    # url es la url completa con los parametros necesarios
    if optSel == 1:
        try:
            for i in range(0,10):
                r = str(0).zfill(4)
                urlI = str(i)
                print r + urlI # it's only to verify that works fine.
                url = baseUrl + r + urlI
                main(url, out_folder)
        except ValueError:
            print "Introduce el rango correcto"
    elif optSel == 2:
        try:
            for i in range(10,100):
                r = str(0).zfill(3)
                urlI = str(i)
                print r + urlI # it's only to verify that works fine.
                url = baseUrl + r + urlI
                main(url, out_folder)
        except ValueError:
            print "Introduce el rango correcto"
    elif optSel < 0:
        print "Valor inferior a 0"
    else:
        print "Algo ha salido mal"
```

Comment: I suppose that I should remove the continue and break too, because it doesn't work if I don't do it. Now, without the while it works fine save every image of the urls. However, now I have another problem (related with the main function that saves the text in csv), should I make another question or I could ask right here?

Comment: Right. sorry. I forgot to take those out.

Comment: Don't worry Robert Moskal, you have help me nicely!

Answer (score 1):

You have to move the line below inside `for` loops:

```
main(url, out_folder)
```

That is, something like this:

```
while True:
    if optSel == 1:
        try:
            for i in range(0,10):
                r = str(0).zfill(4)
                urlI = str(i)
                print r + urlI
                url = baseUrl + r + urlI
                main(url, out_folder)
        except ValueError:
            print "Introduce el rango correcto"
            continue
```

Comment: This helps, but makes it so that this code is run forever. The "while" loop should go away too.

Comment: @RobertMoskal In this case the `while` loop is actually superfluous and can be safely removed!

Comment: Thanks for your answer Jahängir! The answer of @RobertMoskal have solve my question.

Comment: But hey, the are the same :) He removed the `while` loop and added the main() inside `for` loops.